# Show that doesn't exist a continuous differentiable surjective function $\gamma : [0,1] \to [0,1]^2$

Tags: analysis

Show that doesn't exist a continuous differentiable surjective function 
$\gamma : [0,1] \to [0,1]^2$

As I had as exercise during semester and now I am repeating homework this one I couldn't solve and since then I do not have idea to show it.

Comment: You're asking about a function $\;\gamma=(f(x),g(x)):I\to I^2\;,\;\;I:=[0,1]\;$ . What does it mean for such a function to be "differentiable"? That each of its two coordinate functions are?

Comment: @DonAntonio It means that both f(x), g(x) are differentiable in that interval!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\gamma $ is continuously differentiable, $\gamma'$ has a maximum on $I$. That is, for all $t\in I$ there is an $M\ge 0$ such that $\left \| \gamma' \right \|=\max_{t\in I} (\vert f'(t)\vert,\vert g'(t)\vert )<M$.

Now, by MVT, we have

$\tag1\vert f(t)-f(s)\vert \le M\vert t-s\vert$ and $\tag2\vert g(t)-g(s)\vert \le M\vert t-s\vert$.

Fix $N\in \mathbb N$, such that $M^{2}/N<1/2$, and cover $I$ by open intervals of length $1/N$. Then, by $(1)$ and $(2)$, the image of $\gamma $ is covered by open boxes, each of area no more than $M^{2}(1/N) ^{2}$. There are $N$ of them, so that total area of the cover is $M^{2}/N<1/2$, by construction, so the image of $\gamma $ cannot be all of $I\times I$ since the area of $I\times I=1.$